# How to use crypto_modular_inverse in PROLOG?

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment where I have to code an Affine Cipher, the thing is, use of the function crypto_modular_inverse is required.

Here's the statement:

D(y) = crypto modular inverse(a) * (y - b) mod m

I searched [documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=crypto%3Acrypto_modular_inverse/3), but information is scarce and no examples are given.

I need to understand how this function so any nudges is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this walkthrough of an affine cipher: https://crypto.interactive-maths.com/affine-cipher.html

> D(y) = crypto modular inverse(a) * (y - b) mod m

For encryption key values a=5 and b=8 and an alphabet of 26 encryptable characters, the crypto modular inverse is

```
?- crypto_modular_inverse(5, 26, C).   % a=5 and alphabet length m=26
C = 21
```

I made this, where the maplist lines do the `(A*X+B) mod M` and `cmi(a)*(y-b) mod m` transforms along with a dodge around subtracting 97 which is the ASCII Character code of lowercase `a` to bring the letters down from 97,98,99... to 0,1,2... for the crypto math then adding 97 bringing them back up to printable ASCII characters:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

affine_a_b_plain_to_cipher(A, B, Plain, Cipher) :-
    string_codes(Plain, PlainCodes),
    maplist({A,B}/[N,M]>>(M #= ((A*(N-97)+B) mod 26)+97), PlainCodes, CipherCodes),
    string_codes(Cipher, CipherCodes).

affine_a_b_cipher_to_plain(A, B, Cipher, Plain) :-
    string_codes(Cipher, CipherCodes),
    crypto_modular_inverse(A, 26, C),
    maplist({C,B}/[N,M]>>(M #= (C*((N-97)-B) mod 26)+97), CipherCodes, PlainCodes),
    string_codes(Plain, PlainCodes).
```

```
?- affine_a_b_plain_to_cipher(5, 8, "affine cipher", Cipher).
Cipher = "ihhwvcvswfrcp"

?- affine_a_b_cipher_to_plain(5, 8, "ihhwvcvswfrcp", Plain).
Plain = "affinencipher"
```

Fixing the alphabet to include space, uppercase, symbols, etc. is left as an exercise for the reader.